# Any way to make a device believe that an app was downloaded from play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

Is there any way to make a device  believe that an app was downloaded from play store, not having to turn off Unknown sources?

Comment: Is there *any* way to make an believe it was installed from the Play Store, sure... Can this be done easily? Probably not. If you can figure out how it is verifying this information we might be able to formulate a solution. Also, knowing what app and it's source, the device, why you can't just install it from the Play Store, etc. would be very useful information. Also be aware, if this is an attempt to "pirate" an app, we will not assist you in any way.

Comment: @acejavelin ok,edited my question to make it more proper.

Comment: Turning on Unknown Sources does not stop an app from checking it's validity, it simply allows loading an application from a different source. And no, you cannot install an app from outside the play store on a device without enabling Unknown Sources.